# Error getting user's name and email from the associated model in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am creating a webiste where people can debate with each other. It has 4 main models - post, for_the_motion, against_the_motion, and user( added in the respective order). I ran a migration and made a association between for model and against model.

For each view in "for" model I want to show which user added that particular motion. But I am getting an error

> undefined method `image_url' for nil:NilClass

Stuck from long time on this. This is how the models look

**user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
has_many :posts
has_many :fors
has_many :againsts
class << self
    def from_omniauth(auth_hash)
            user = find_or_create_by(uid: auth_hash['uid'], provider: auth_hash['provider'])
            user.name = auth_hash['info']['name']
            user.image_url = auth_hash['info']['image']
            user.url = auth_hash['info']['urls'][user.provider.capitalize]
            user.save!
            user
    end
end
```

end

**for.rb**

```
class For < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :post, optional: true
 belongs_to :user,optional: true 
end
```

**post.rb**

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :fors, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :againsts, dependent: :destroy
 belongs_to :user, optional: true
end
```

**against.rb**

```
class Against < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post, optional: true
  belongs_to :user, optional:true
end
```

CONTROLLERS

posts_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
def index
    @posts = Post.all
end

def land
end

def show 
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def new
    @post = Post.new
end

def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.user = current_user

    if @post.save
        redirect_to @post
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
private
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title)
end

end
```

fors_controller.rb

```
class ForsController < ApplicationController

    def create
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
        @for = @post.fors.create(fors_params)
        @for.user = current_user
        redirect_to post_path(@post)
    end



  private
    def fors_params
      params.require(:for).permit(:content)
    end

end
```

sessions_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    begin
            @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env['omniauth.auth'])
            session[:user_id] = @user.id
         # flash[:success] = "Welcome, #{@user.name}!"
    rescue
            # flash[:warning] = "There was an error while trying to authenticate you..."
    end
    redirect_to root_path

    def destroy
        if current_user
            session.delete(:user_id)
                # flash[:success] = 'See you!'
        end
        redirect_to root_path
    end
end
end
```

**This is where I am getting the error**

```
<h1><%=@post.title%></h1>
<div class="fort">
<h3>For the motion</h3>
<%@post.fors.each do |f|%>
    <p><%=f.content%></p>
    <p><%=f.user.image_url%></p>/*This is where errors arise*/
<%end%> 
  <%= render "fors/form"%>
  </div>
<div class="against">
    <h3>Against the motion</h3>
    <%@post.againsts.each do |f|%>
        <p><%=f.content%></p>
        <p><%= @post.user.name%></p>
    <%end%> 

      <%= render "againsts/form"%>
</div>
```

Here is the github link for any other required information
https://github.com/sarfrazbaig/DebatingSociety2

Comment: what is the filename of the view file? Also what action does the error occur? is it on `posts_controller#create` or `fors_controller#create`?

Comment: for_controller#create... I just checked it now.. when I am creating a new post the user is automatically getting added in the post model. But this not happening in the case of for_controller. @Jay-ArPolidario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you missed saving the `.user` on **fors_controller.rb**:

```
class ForsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @for = @post.fors.create(fors_params)
    # .create above already will save a new For record in DB
    # therefore your @for.user assignation will be only assigned in memory, but not yet in DB
    @for.user = current_user
    # you'll need to save it again afterwards:
    @for.save
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  end

  # ...
end
```

### Suggestion:

- use `.new` instead of `.create` to not-yet-save into the DB, and only call save when everything that you need to assign is already assigned.

  ```
  class ForsController < ApplicationController

    def create
      @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
      @for = @post.fors.new(fors_params)
      @for.user = current_user
      @for.save
      redirect_to post_path(@post)
    end

    # ...
  end
  ```
- Take note that you would still encounter that error even if you already updated your code with the above; this is because currently your `For` records in the DB all are missing the `.user` value. You'll have to manually assign and save the `.user` accordingly for each `For` record, and probably best that you'd write a...

  ```
  class For < ApplicationRecord
    validates :user, presence: true
  end
  ```

... validation so that this error will be prevented in the future.

Comment: Thank you it worked like a charm. Now what I am bumping into is when I log out of the system, it says cannot find sessions#destroy action even though it is present.

Comment: No prob :) what does the log output say when you try to log out? Is it GET or DELETE request?

Comment: Started DELETE "/logout" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-09-25 18:05:49 +0530
  
AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'destroy' could not be found for SessionsController):

Comment: Oh wait your **def destroy** is inside the **def create** in your **sessions_controller.rb**. Move it out from there; that should work.

Comment: The error is coming again even after adding all this. It broke down again once I added a modal to keep the two forms. I removed the modal and it started working again.

Comment: what error? were you referring to the logout error? or the original question you have? If it's the original question, have you read my "Take note that you would..." above? Have you already manually updated the `.user` for each `For` record?

Comment: I did a rake db:reset. The problem arises when i move the form to a modal. Then it again gives me nil user error? I cannot trace back the mistake. Is their any mistake in the form?

Comment: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass):
        15: <h3>For the motion</h3>
        16: <%@post.fors.each do |f|%>
        17:  <p><%=f.content%></p>
        18:  <p><%= f.user.name%></p>
        19: <%end%> 
        20:   </div>
        21: 
  
This is the change in the view          <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" href="#modal3">Modal</a>

  <!-- Modal Structure -->
  <div id="modal3" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
   <%= render "fors/form"%>     
     
    </div>
  </div>

Comment: In that error, I am pretty sure `@post` is not nil, and that `@post.fors` is an array, and that then `@post.fors[X].user` is nil (where X is some index integer), and therefore the problem is that either 1) one of the `.fors` array is not a `For` object, or 2) that one one of the `.fors` array still doesn't have an associated `User` record even though you already added my code above; which then mostly likely the problem is somewhere else where you are also creating a `For` record.

Comment: In order to debug where the creation of a "For-record-having-empty-user" is coming from, please do add my suggested presence validation above: `validates :user, presence: true`. Then, reset your DB again, and try to reproduce again your scenario. Somewhere on the line, you should encounter another error (presence validation error) before you even reached this current error of yours that you just showed. Let me know then any progress afterwards.

Comment: I tried all this. I am getting a strange error. It works fine normally. But when I move the form to a modal, it shows me an error. It is getting saved in the database with correct user id ( I am checking it from rails admin ). How does moving something to a different HTML element is breaking the engine is what I am not getting

Comment: Try adding `<% byebug if f.user.nil? %>` just after the line `<%@post.fors.each do |f|%>`. Whenever `byebug` is called, the server will be "paused", and there while paused you can run ruby methods and inspect the variables. i.e. try entering `f.user` there on the rails server while it is paused. Hopefully you'll figure out something while inspecting stuff. To unpause, enter `c`

Answer (score 0):

One of the `@post.fors` is lacking a user, which is permitted by the `belongs_to :user, optional: true` in your `For` model.

You can restrict your query to showing only `fors` that have an associated user: 
`@post.fors.joins(:users)` or you can use the safe navigation operator to return `nil` when attempting to read the `image_url` for a non-existent user - `f.user&.image_url`

Comment: This is the error I got "Can't join 'For' to association named 'users'; perhaps you misspelled it?"